# Unable to connect to API getting error java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

When I am try to access link via Office networking getting `java.net.UnknownHostException` exception. I am trying access via Home network its working fine.

Office network is using *proxy.pac* file, which I am unable to find the proxy server. Can you please help with the alternative code.

Code:

```
Response response = given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().when().
                get("https://www.nseindia.com/api/search/autocomplete?q=HCLTECH"
```

Comment: I am getting "You don't have permission to access "http://www.nseindia.com/" on this server." when I try this URL ..

Comment: It seems your office network does not let you resolve the host name. This is either intentional or accidental.  You'd have to ask your office network admininstrator.

Comment: Hi. @user16632363, I have tried in browser its working fine. And also I have tried via Postman via System proxy I am able to access it. Only via Java code I am facing issue. There are some many IP address available in pac file, not able to find the proxy server details.